# Element outside accessing data in an outside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a list that has a ng-repeat `details`.
When I hover over one of the `li`,   I want the div called `background`which lies outside of the ng-repeat to change it's background to the `details`'s url.

But I don't know how to have the outside element access the ng-repeat's data.

plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/lGRfE9YGYN645Ztpr94K?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.details = [
   { "name": "Employees", "url":"https://i.pinimg.com/736x/76/47/9d/76479dd91dc55c2768ddccfc30a4fbf5--pikachu-halloween-costume-diy-halloween-costumes.jpg" },
   { "name": "Support", "url":"https://i.pinimg.com/736x/76/47/9d/76479dd91dc55c2768ddccfc30a4fbf5--pikachu-halloween-costume-diy-halloween-costumes.jpg" }
    ];

});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.8"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="background">
  <ul ng-repeat="detail in details">
    <li>{{detail.name}}

    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use `ng-mouseenter` and `ng-mouseleave` on hover. Set one variable to true/false and use that variable in `ng-class` to add your custom class.

Comment: Problem isn't using those, it's I don't know how to access the ng-repeat items.

Comment: that variable will accessible through out controller scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`ng-mouseover`** on li item and apply the background using **`ng-style`** over the **`div`**

```
<div ng-style="{'background-image':'url(' + bgUrl + ')'}">
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.details = [
   { "name": "Employees", "url":"https://i.pinimg.com/736x/76/47/9d/76479dd91dc55c2768ddccfc30a4fbf5--pikachu-halloween-costume-diy-halloween-costumes.jpg" },
   { "name": "Support", "url":"https://i.stack.imgur.com/IosVb.png" }
    ];
     $scope.applybackground=function(detail){
        $scope.bgUrl = detail.url;
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-style="{'background-image':'url(' + bgUrl + ')'}">
    <ul ng-repeat="detail in details">
      <li ng-mouseenter="applybackground(detail)">{{detail.name}}
      </li>
 </ul>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-mouseover to access the detail object in the controller.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="background" ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{myBackgroundUrl}})'}">
    <ul ng-repeat="detail in details">
      <li ng-mouseover="onHover(detail)">{{detail.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

At the controller:

```
$scope.myBackgroundUrl = '';
$scope.onHover = function(detail) {
  console.log(detail.url)
  $scope.myBackgroundUrl = detail.url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use ng-mouseover something like

```
<div class="background" style="background-image:url('{{backGroundUrl}}')">
<ul >
    <li ng-mouseover="change(detail.url)" ng-repeat="detail in details">
      {{detail.name}}

    </li>

  $scope.change= function(url){
      $scope.backGroundUrl=url;
    }
```

[Here is working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/UFnKNhYGxTOJIZnrNJnH?p=preview)